# How to contain four divs equally, with 50% width and the same height, into a container with 100% width?

Tags: html, css

So, I am trying to make four boxes that show different stypes. I want it to look like the below but with 50% of its width. I have set the width to 50% and it has not worked even though I defined the HTML/body width as 100%.

```css
.steps{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
    align-content: center; 
}

.topsteps{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
    align-content: center;
}

.bottomsteps{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
    align-content: center;
}

#right{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
}

#left {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

.boxstep-red{
    border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    background-color: #ff383f;
    padding: 50px;
}

.boxstep-blue{
    border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    background-color: #caebf2;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
        <div class="topsteps">
              <div class="boxstep-red" id="left">
                <p>plan</p>            
              </div>
              <div class="boxstep-blue" id="right"> 
                <p>organize</p>
              </div>
          </div><br>
          <div class="bottomsteps">
              <div class="boxstep-blue" id="right">
                <p>DO</p>
              </div>
              <div class="boxstep-red" id="left">
                <p>ace</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I just need to figure out a way to make it 50% width so that it takes up the total of the webpage instead of just an area in the center. Because when I set it to width: 50% instead of width: 150px for the #right and #left and it does not work, what can I add/tweak to make the width of the boxes 50% while still retaining the original format (4 boxes joined together in the middle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check below snippet it's working. You need to give `width:100%` to `topsteps` `bottomsteps` and then remove width for `right` `left` in pixel and add `50%` this will take full screen with 50% width of each box top and bottom. Hope this will help you.

```css
.steps{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
    align-content: center; 
}

.topsteps{
  width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
    align-content: center;
}

.bottomsteps{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
    align-content: center;
}

#right{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

#left {
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.boxstep-red{
    border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    background-color: #ff383f;
    padding: 50px;
}

.boxstep-blue{
    border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    background-color: #caebf2;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
        <div class="topsteps">
              <div class="boxstep-red" id="left">
                <p>plan</p>            
              </div>
              <div class="boxstep-blue" id="right"> 
                <p>organize</p>
              </div>
          </div><br>
          <div class="bottomsteps">
              <div class="boxstep-blue" id="right">
                <p>DO</p>
              </div>
              <div class="boxstep-red" id="left">
                <p>ace</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @sunidhi If its worked perfectly then please accept answer.